# Linking together two models in a Razor Pages/MVC asp application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

So. I am working on a Razor based website that functions as a business manager.

I am trying to link an address to a printer in the creation page.

The Printer Model looks like this: 
public class Printer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

```
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Machine ID")]
    public string MachineID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Log ID")]
    public int Log_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Lease ID")]
    public int Lease_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Serial_Number { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Solution { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Additional Info")]
    public string Additional_Info { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Installation Date")]
    public DateTime InstallationDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mono Click")]
    public float Mono_Click { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Colour Click")]
    public float Colour_Click { get; set; }

    public int Minimum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Parts Warranty")]
    public int Parts_Warranty { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IT Support")]
    public int IT_Support { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Contract Type")]
    public string Contract_Type { get; set; }

    public Company_Site Site { get; set; }
    public Printer_Model Model { get; set; }
    public Address Previous_Address { get; set; }
}
```

The Address Model looks like this:
public class Address
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

```
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address_1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address_2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string Town_City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Post_Code { get; set; }
}
```

To try and link them together I have this in my Create.cshtml.cs file:

```
public List<SelectListItem> PrevAddress { get; set; }
public IActionResult OnGet()
   {
        PrevAddress = _context.Address.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.ID.ToString(),
            Text = a.Address_1 + " " + a.Town_City + " " + a.Post_Code 
        }).ToList();
        return Page();
    }
```

Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Printer.Previous_Address.ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Printer.Previous_Address.ID" name="PrevAddress" asp-items="Model.PrevAddress" class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Printer.Previous_Address.ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

However, when I run it through my form no value gets sent to the foreign key field in the database even when I have explicitly selected one of my addresses from the dropdown box. Any help in this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set an item as selected in the select tag helper, you can do so by assigning its value to the property specified by the `asp-for` attribute.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists#setting-selected-items<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup>*Disclosure - I own the Learn Razor Pages site*

Comment: I have followed the steps you gave but now rather than not setting the Foreign Key value (linking the two objects) it gives me the following SQL error:
`SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Printer_Printer_Model_ModelID". The conflict occurred in database "_360_Office_ManagementContext-577009b7-1da0-4f2f-8dbc-3196d6e7a3d9", table "dbo.Printer_Model", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Please can I have some advice?

Comment: So the original question has been resolved? If so, you should accept an answer, and then post a new question about problems elsewhere in your application. I don't think the moderators will be too happy with extended debugging help in the comments section.

Comment: In the meantime, you usually get that message if the foreign key value hasn't been set to an existing PK value in the related table - often it hasn't been set at all. You should debug your app to see what value is being assigned to the FK by the model binder.